# MoveFocus on arrow keys does not work both ways

Tags: c#, wpf

I have strange problem. I have custom made dialog and 3 buttons on it (those are only visual components on dialog). Xaml looks like this:

```
<Button x:Name="PrintBtn" Click="Btn1_Click" Content="Print" 
    IsTabStop="True" Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
    PreviewKeyDown="Btn1_PreviewKeyDown"/>
<Button x:Name="NewBtn" Click="Btn2_Click" Content="New" 
    IsTabStop="True" Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
    PreviewKeyDown="Btn2_PreviewKeyDown"/>
<Button x:Name="CancelBtn" Click="Btn3_Click" Content="Cancel" 
    IsTabStop="True" Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3"
    PreviewKeyDown="Btn3_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

My code for move focus works fine, but in wrong direction:

```
switch (e.Key)
{
    case Key.Left:
        btnX.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));
        break;
    case Key.Right:
        btnX.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

But when I just switch keys and directions, it does not work at all.

```
switch (e.Key)
{
    case Key.Left:
        btnX.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        break;
    case Key.Right:
        btnX.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I have tried everything I could think of, but with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:
Did you tried it without any coding? WPF has a built in arrow navigation based on the structure of your ui elements, most of the times it works pretty well.

Follow-up approach:
I assume your dialog is rendered on top of another userControl or similiar. Therefore it can be that your keyboard focus is somewhere on the other UiControls under the dialog. However, in your case I would also assume a generic solution is not needed, even though it would be nicer to have one. I struggled also a lot with this problem and in the end I hard coded the outcome like this:

```
private void Button_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Right:
                Keyboard.Focus(BtnCanel);
                break;
            case Key.Left:
                Keyboard.Focus(BtnApproval);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
```

Even if this lacks the automation of navigation processes it's an explicit statement of your desired behavior and won't be changed if something in your Ui changes. Therefore I tend to go this cumbersome way on small Ui's like a dialog if the natural wpf navigation doesn't fit my needs.